# Form state values problem

Tags: forms

I dont understand the problem im facing.

I'm building a big form (in which you can add products, modify quantity, etc etc and validate.

I'm getting consistency data problem between what's in `$form_state['values']` and what's in `$form_state['input']`

`$form_state['values']` are never up-to-date ...

if I change a quantity field value, and then validate the ofrm, I will find the right quantity in `$form_state['input']` but not in `$form_state['values']`.

Say it passes the validation step, if I submit a second time the form, then I will have the correct values in `$form_state['values']`.

**Another example** : The validation fails if a quantitu is set to 0. When the form display itself after the failure, all quantity fields are reset to the value they were after the previous form loading (Am I clear enough ?)

I dont understand what could make this happen ...

Found this post : [When are '$form_state['values'] copied to '$form' on rebuild?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124984/when-are-form-statevalues-copied-to-form-on-rebuild?rq=1)

Petroll commented it :

> When you submit a form with user input, the input gets stored in
>   $form_state['input'] and later (after validation) in
>   $form_state['values']. But when you, then, rebuild the form, the
>   values are (and AFAIK have to be) are ?somehow? given as parameters to
>   element process functions (that create the FAPI arrays of elements).

That make sense... If validation fails, `$form_state['values']` is not updated with `$form_state['input']`. So the form is rebuild with the old values.

But What I dont understand is why all the values are reseted ...

Lets say Ive 5 products. If I modify each quantity, and I set one of them to 0, the validation will fail and all my inputs will be lost.

Comment: in which step are you accesssing that values? Validation? Build step? Process phase? Form alter step? Adding your code might help.

Comment: some examples : When the validation process fails, old values are used as default values in all inputs.

Comment: Are you taking the `$form_state` as reference?

Comment: I will try to add code but wont do it before tomorrow I think. Meanwhile ill add others examples

Comment: yes form_state is used by reference everywhere  (validation, submit, other functions)

Comment: What process is used to recreate the form after validation fails ? I looked at https://www.drupal.org/files/fapi_workflow_7.x_v1.1.png and it seems the built form is simply returned if no cache.

Comment: Without seeing code to reproduce this issue it's impossible to help you

Comment: Just added the biggest part of the code : here youll find the building, the process, the validation and submission. Ive omitted useless functions and change variables names

Comment: It seems I find the culprit ... be dont know for sure beacause Ive tested too much things in a row ... Im gonna update the thread when Ill find

Comment: Nope ... still the same ...

Comment: Ive cleared the cache but could it be related to session or anything persistant on my computer ?

Comment: No one to help me out ?

Comment: At a guess: `$lignes[$i]['ref'] = array(` in the `else` has an unconditional `#value` of `''`, which will overwrite any user input. Change that to `#default_value` instead

Comment: Could have been that ... but no. Ive already tired.
Using `   $lignes[$i]['qte'] = array(
     '#type' => 'item',
     '#default_value' => '',
   );  `

or just `$lignes[$i]['qte'] = array(
     '#default_value' => '',
   );` 

... Still the same

Comment: I did try to delete everything in the `else` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did find a solution : #after_build attribute added to my textfield.

Then added a new function to check if the `form_state['input']['mytextfield']` is set. If so, using it to change the `#value` of the element.

important : altering `#default_value` in the after_build function didn't work, had to change the #value

Comment: and an other way to keep user input after validation errors :

https://www.drupal.org/node/671574#comment-9440407