# How is a form rebuild if it fails validation?

Tags: forms

I wondering how it is rebuild if validation fails.

Say you have several inputs. Change them all and submit. A certain rule isnt validated so the form validation fails (with a form_set_error).

What is the process to redisplay the form ?

Im struggling with input/validation erros and from what I've seen, it doesn't rebuild, even if I would use `REBUILD=TRUE`

Comment: No process, as long as the same form comes out on the page you've submitted to, Drupal will rebuild it for you

Comment: Rebuilt it for me, meaning it will process the build_form function Ive created to build the original form ?

Comment: You've lost me - what's a build_form function?

Comment: ^^ the 'drupal_get_form' function ...
The thing is : Ive added some logs in different places in the drupal_get_form function, and it seems that if validation fails, no log is triggered

Comment: I confirm what Ive just written : using watchdog I can clearly see that only the validate function is processed. No rebuilding.

Comment: in my case at least ... the question is : is my case normal ?

Comment: Sorry, might be getting crossed wires with terminology here - by "rebuilt" do you mean literally that the form array will be passed to `drupal_rebuild_form()`? If so then no, if there are form errors it won't be. There are loads more comments than code in [`drupal_process_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_process_form/7) (where this all kicks off), might be worth giving those a once over to understand what's going on

Comment: this is what I thought you were meaning ... ^^
So Ive added logs to confirm that, despite the fact that the form is displayed again (rebuilt you would say ?), the function `mymodule_form(...)` is not called again.

Comment: That might be more to do with how you're rendering the form - is it a page callback? Embedded in a block? Something else?

Comment: a page callback ... yesterday I post another question, leading to the same probelm I confess, but as I need help and the other post was maybe not very clear ... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146270/form-state-values-problem/146378#146378     
ive added the code you were asking